# How to handle jackson.jasonMappingException in mulesoft

Tags: java, mule, elixir-jason

when i am sending a request through postman, i am getting a following exception.

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.LinkedHashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.Object] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method.

i am using mulesoft, should i make change in an xml file or add an annotation in java file?

Comment: Please add the following information to your question: 1) Mule version (note: MuleSoft is a company name, not the product), 2) Flow (as XML text), 3) Java source code, 4) Input payload

Answer (score 0):

Probably the input JSON doesn't match the expected format of the code or it is invalid. It is not possible to be more specific in the answer if you are not more specific in the question and provide all the details.